# Why isn't shadowbox showing in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shadowbox

The shadowbox I am trying to fix in IE is located here:

http://www.carolinedawes.com.au/abc-gardening-australia.html

The HTML is

```
<div class="hero-image">
  <a href="m/abc-gardening-australia-caroline-dawes.mov" rel="shadowbox;height=272;width=480">
    <img src="i/abc-gardening-australia-caroline-dawes-gardening-adelaide.jpg" alt="caroline dawes" />
  </a>
</div>
```

The JS is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="j/shadowbox.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Shadowbox.init({
    players: ["qt"]
  });
</script>
```

Any ideas? Or success stories in IE?

Comment: Seems to work fine in IE7 & 8 for me, except when closing the shadowbox while the movie is loading the video frame sits there for a while then goes away.

Comment: Why isn't this working consistently? I get no video only the grayed-out effect...

Answer (score 1):

I can't really help you cause I've no experience with it, but some of these users seems to provide a couple of solutions:

> http://www.shadowbox-js.com/forum.html#nabble-td1309456
>
> https://realmac.macdock.com/realmacsoftware/2007/support/viewtopic.php?pid=215177

See if these may help.

Comment: These sites were helpful in that they acknowledge that there is an inconsistency with Shadowbox and IE - however none of the solutions worked.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I trial was deserved, thought.